# AWS Lambda and API Gateway response integration issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have deployed AWS stack with a Lambda function and an API gateway. After deployment I tested Lambda function independently and it works fine but when I invoke it using AWS API Gateway, it fails with `

> Internal Error: 502

I looked at cloudwatch logs and it says

> Endpoint response body before transformations: null

I am returning my response from **Lambda (Python 3.6)** in following way -

```
body = {
        "message": "Success!!"
    }

response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": json.dumps(body),
    "isBase64Encoded": False,
}
return response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Actually the code is correct. I made few changes and took the above code outside handler. So my handler was calling this new function and it was returning response to handler but I missed to return the received response again from handler to API gateway.